# How to resolve "Waiting for Debugger" on android 12

Tags: android

It has been several days, that after I updated android studio to Arctic Fox then on Android 12, I cannot debug, I cannot somehow attach the process to debug.

Though, a phone with older Android 9 it is just working fine.
Same code, but different android version.

I hope someone could help me.
I have added debuggable in release and in manifest but all seems fail.

Comment: Do an adb kill-server then reboot it.  ALso try rebooting the device/emulator.  These usually fix this, generally something is just in a screwy state.

Comment: i have tried this a couple of times. Both Wireless debugging and  usb debugging fails. i have also done adb kill-server and adb-start server to no avail. I am using a Samsung Tablet A6 10.1 with android 12 lineage OS. I have alos tried the Selected Apps and select nothing.

Comment: hi, if you run "adb devices" can you see the device? you have developer options enable on your device? only you have problems when try to debug? any log you can share?

Answer (score 0):

I have notice this message too.
Run the Virtual Android first and after the system appears click to Run the code.
The application will install and execute after.
When you click in Run the code before the Virtual Android crash and you need reinstall that. I couldn't remove the message, but the system works.

Answer (score 0):

Go into Developer options on the device, scroll down to Wait for debugger and toggle the switch to on and then to off. This should clear the problem.